# use of unassigned local variable `total`

Tags: c#, local-variables, unassigned-variable

I want to have a sum of all intervals , but I write this code I have an error stating: use of unassigned local variable `total` ?

```
enter TimeSpan total;
foreach (var grp in query)
{
  TimeSpan interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(grp.Minuut); 
  TimeSpan intervalH = TimeSpan.FromHours(grp.Sum);

  interval = interval + intervalH;
  total += interval;
  string timeInterval = interval.ToString();   
  dataGridView2.Rows.Add(i++, grp.Id, grp.Sum, grp.Minuut,timeInterval);
}
```

Comment: Your last edit destroyed your formatting and the `enter TimeSpan` part makes no sense. Can you revert or fix that?

Comment: declare and initialize 'total' before adding 'interval' to it

Answer (score 7):

Start with:

```
TimeSpan total = TimeSpan.Zero;
```

Incrementing a variable that has no value makes no sense. So it's only natural for this to be a compiler error.

While *fields* get initialized to 0, local variables must be assigned to before they are first read. In your program `total += interval;` reads `total` in order to increment it. In the first iteration of your loop it thus wouldn't have been assigned a value.

Answer (score 1):

```
total += interval;
```

Is wrong when total has no value assigned at all... What are you going to add interval too?

Comment: I just want to have a total of all rows in my datagridview , the column is filled with a timespan.

Comment: @Nick_BE Just initialize it to 0. Or whatever the default C'tor is.

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize total value **before use**

```
 TimeSpan total = new TimeSpan();,
```

then code should work.

Answer (score 0):

No initial value is ever assigned to total.  You have to assign a value before you use it.

Comment: TimeSpan total = new TimeSpan(0); is what I needed